# how use eval() functinon to workable a base64 encoded script?

Tags: php, eval, decode, encode

please see the code below :

```
<?php
$str1 = 'My Name Is : ';
$str2 = 'Dvid!';
echo $str1.$str2;
?>
```

just a simple php code.
i want to encode (for example base64) this php file and use encoded php file instead of normal.
so the base64 encode of the codes upper is like below :

```
PD9waHANCiRzdHIxID0gJ015IE5hbWUgSXMgOiAnOw0KJHN0cjIgPSAnRHZpZCEnOw0KZWNobyAkc3RyMS4kc3RyMjsNCj8+DQo=
```

now how can i use that encoded php file?
i think eval() function is the answer!
so i changed the php file like this for use :

```
<?php
$str = 'PD9waHANCiRzdHIxID0gJ015IE5hbWUgSXMgOiAnOw0KJHN0cjIgPSAnRHZpZCEnOw0KZWNobyAkc3RyMS4kc3RyMjsNCj8+DQo=';
eval("base64_decode(\$str);");
?>
```

my problem is i really do n't know why the output is blank (white screen)?
how can i fix this problem?

**EDIT 1 :**
i test using include instead after answers like below and i got an error :

```
<?php
include 'data://text/plain;base64,PD9waHANCiRzdHIxID0gJ015IE5hbWUgSXMgOiAnOw0KJHN0cjIgPSAnRHZpZCEnOw0KZWNobyAkc3RyMS4kc3RyMjsNCj8';
?>
```

and error :
[image: that error]

**important note :**
 i am looking for a way without any changing on server configurations, because we do n't have access on remote host after publish...

**EDIT 2 :**
i removed

```
<?php
?>
```

part from base64 encode -> still have blank screen.

thanks for attention

Comment: What's wrong with `file_get_contents` to open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. You're evaluating the code:

   ```
   base64_decode($str);
   ```

   which does nothing.
2. There are still `<?php` and `?>` tags in there, which `eval` can't handle.

So, one interesting solution is to use `include` instead, with a PHP `data://` URI:

```
include 'data://text/plain;base64,PD9waHANCiRzdHIxID0gJ015IE5hbWUgSXMgOiAnOw0KJHN0cjIgPSAnRHZpZCEnOw0KZWNobyAkc3RyMS4kc3RyMjsNCj8+DQo=';
```

Note that you'll need `allow_url_include` enabled for this to work.

Comment: hi, but i need a workable web site at last(that echo just was a sample - i am talking about a complete web site with many html elements), not a plain text. also your code has three error. would you please insert the entire code!

Comment: @MoonLight: This is not plain text, nor does it contain errors. Read the whole thing.

Comment: why base64_decode($str); does nothing -> it returns php codes (as string). so we can evaluate that string.

Comment: @MoonLight: First, yes, `base64_decode` returns the PHP as a string to evaluate. However, you're not evaluating it correctly; see Cole Johnson's answer for that. Anyway, the point is that you can't use `eval` on it anyway, because it has `<?php ?>` tags in it; `eval` only handles "raw" PHP code. Finally, see the footnote for why you get the errors. To quote: *"Note that you'll need allow_url_include enabled for this to work."* And that's impossible without reconfiguring the server, as you request. What's the point of this, anyway? Obfuscation? If it is, don't bother. Base64 won't work.

Comment: we can fix that error with reconfiguration of server. but i don't have remote access to my host server for doing that. can we do something about eval() function or show me another workable Obfuscation method!

Comment: @MoonLight: It depends on why you're obfuscating your code in the end. Is it going to be licensed to others or something? Or is this just in case your server is broken into? Something else?

Comment: @MoonLight: Unfortunately, that's very malicious. I'm not going to tell you a technique for making any kind of malware, even if your intentions are good. Sorry.